# Where can I buy a multi input splitter box for two computers?

Tags: hub, splitters

Since remote working is the new norm and my company doesnt want that I use my own glorious computer but their okayish laptop, I would at least be able to use my own device. So each morning I unplug the hdmi cable of my screen, my mouse, my keyboard, my usb microphone and the jack of my headphone to plug them to the laptop. During the lunch break I move everything back to my tower to move them again after the break. Finally, at 6 o'clock, I unplug and plug all devices to my computer. I am sick of this (and I dont think it is very good for each device).

I bought a hdmi switch for the screen:

[image: HDMI switch]

[source](https://www.amazon.fr/Switch-GANA-Splitter-Commutateur-Blue-Ray/dp/B072J4C42H/ref=sr_1_28?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=Commutateur+Splitter+Box+jack+hdmi+usb&qid=1601458081&sr=8-28)

and I plan to buy one for the jack:

[image: Jack switch]

[source](https://www.amazon.fr/Nobsound-mc102-Mini-passive-Selector-Commutateur/dp/B07C9LVDZC/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=jack+switch&qid=1601457819&sr=8-5)

and I plan to buy one for the usb (mic + keyboard):

[image: usb switch]

[source](https://www.amazon.fr/ABLEWE-Entr%C3%A9es-Sorties-Commutateur-Imprimante/dp/B07WMG6LB7/ref=sr_1_30?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=hub+switch+usb+jack&qid=1601457723&sr=8-30)

I am looking for 3-in-1 solution with all of them. Where can I buy a multi input splitter box for two computers? I cant find one online. Maybe I dont have the right name.

Bonus if it can share the ethernet too.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a Kvm switch. Wikipedia has an [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) about it.

> A KVM switch (with KVM being an abbreviation for "keyboard, video and mouse") is a hardware device that allows a user to control multiple computers from one or more[1](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Kvm-switch-diagram.svg/410px-Kvm-switch-diagram.svg.png) sets of keyboards, video monitors, and mice.

[image: kvm switch]

You can find those in any specialize shop or big enough retailer (e.g. amazon).

[image: kvm in action]

It can be costly though. Some example:

- https://smile.amazon.com/StarTech-com-4-Port-HDMI-Switch-Built/dp/B003AVPUZQ?th=1
- https://smile.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-2-Port-DisplayPort-B004-DPUA2-K/dp/B014LQM8J4
- https://smile.amazon.com/Switch-Support-Wireless-Keyboard-Require/dp/B087NMTBDF
- https://smile.amazon.com/Pasow-Switch-Keyboard-Mouse-Switcher/dp/B0814WKMXV

A lot of kvm switch wont support audio. A solution would be to buy a jack to usb adapter.

[image: jack to usb adpater picture]

[source](https://smile.amazon.com/TROND-External-Adapter-Integrated-Microphone/dp/B07L56C28R/)

Thank you Eegras from the [PCMR Discord](https://rebrand.ly/pcmrdiscord) for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a multimedia KVM switch (just as an example:  [https://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-4-Port-Multimedia-GCS1794-Compliant/dp/B001V9LQ52](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001V9LQ52))

Answer (score 0):

Also to add to the other answer, KVM switches often don't play nice with anything other than USB keyboards and mice.

You will most likely not be able to use it with USB storage drives. Though if you just get two USB hubs and set them near each other, it's not too difficult to use one or the other for external storage.